# I don't know how to make a correct IF that filters if the content of an EditText is different from zero

Tags: android, if-statement, zero

How to avoid 0 and 0.0 and 0.00 and 0.000 and 0.0000 e all the other "zeros" the user can type. If were for only one, I know how to do with string comparison, but I have this problem with several strings, but only one meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to parse your string into `double` and compare it to `0`:

```
if(Double.valueOf(yourText) == 0)
{
     //do something scary
}
```